# combobox in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, combobox

I would like to show cost if city is selected.

The table is like this:

```
id |  city    |   cost  |
1  |  NY      |   1000  |
2  |  Chicago |   2000  |
```

And below is the code that I have tried but failed:

controller

```
function order()
{
................................
$data['result']=$this->order_model->get_kota()->result();
$this->load->view('order_view',$data);
}
```

model

```
function get_kota()
{
return $this->db->get('kota');
}
```

view

```
<select>
<?php foreach($result as $data)
{ ?>
<option value='<?php echo $data->id_kota?>'><?php echo $data->city?></option><?php }?>
</select>

//if i select option then form input automatically show cost???
<input type='text'><?php echo $data->cost?></input>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use AJAX to fetch the cost. Write a AJAX function on select box's OnChange Event..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the result set in a JavaScript variable like so:

```
var results = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
```

Then, respond to the change event of the select box, by searching the city id in `results` and fill the input field with the corresponding cost

Something along these lines:

```
$("select").change(function(){
   id = $(this).val();
   for (i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
   if (results[i].id==id) {
   $("input").val(results[i].cost);
    }
   }
});
```

AJAX request is redundant in this case IMHO, because the entire data is already fetched from the server.